# How to Validate Only Strings on Nested Object with Joi

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, joi

My goal is to allow a nested object of an arbitrary depth that can contain anything. Within that nested object I want to perform extra validation only on strings.

So, the object could look like this:

```
{
  "features": {
    "feature1": "value1",
    "feature2": false,
    "feature3": 321,
    "feature4": {
      "something": "else"
    },
    "feature5": ["something", "more"]
}
```

For all of the string values I want to perform some extra validation, but for everything else, I just want to accept it as valid.

I am only partially there, and need some help handling nested objects and such. Here's what I've got:

```
var providerSchema = Joi.object().keys({
  features: Joi.object().pattern(/^/, Joi.alternatives()
    .when(Joi.ref('features'), {
      is: Joi.string(),
      then: validateBlacklist(['<', '>']), 
      otherwise: Joi.any()
    }))
});

function validateBlacklist(list) {
  let regex = new RegExp(`^(?:(?!${list.join('|')}).)*$`);
  return Joi.string().regex(regex)
    .options({language: { string: { regex: { base: 'contains an invalid character'}}}});
}
```

**Problem 1: alternatives().when() is Only Accepting Strings**
Currently, only strings are accepted in the features object. It seems that the alternatives().when() part isn't working correctly. I was trying to check whether or not the reference was a string; if it was, then perform the extra validation via validateBlaclist(), otherwise, accept it.

**Problem 2: No Support for Nested Objects**
Objects within objects aren't supported with my validation. This nesting needs to be supported for an arbitrary depth since this features object could contain anything.

Does anyone know where to go with this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.